# Why did my CDR/DVR stop writing after I installed updates to Ubuntu 18.04.5

Tags: cd, read-only, burning

I've been using the same system for years now, and since Ubuntu 14.04 have been able to write CD's on it without a problem, but now Ubuntu 18.04.5 sees both my CDR/DVDR as 'read only' and that doesn't make a bit of sense to me.

Using Brasero has been one of the big plus's to having Ubuntu installed on my system. But now it wont even recognize either of my CD writer/DVD writer as a writer.

What changed and how can I fix it?

Comment: Have you confirmed the drive hasn't just died?   I rarely write CD/DVDs these days, but I've had 3 drives fail (or I concluded had failed) for the last 10 discs I've written, which I gather just relates to the drives getting old. I'm not worried yet, as I kept a number of spares...  Try using a *live* media to write a disc, if it fails there, swap out the drive & you'll likely find the replacement drive works perfectly (ie. dead drive)

Comment: I second trying to do this from a live session to rule out any variables from your current "beaten path" installation.

Comment: You could also try logging in using an older kernel, my prior comment was based on my own recent experience burning discs.. I'm also likely to burn discs on this my primary machine which is on the *development* cycle (ie. *groovy*) and would have only been on *bionic* after 17.10's release until 18.04 was released where it bumped to *cosmic*...  ie. I've not used your combination of software stack  (are you using HWE? or the 5.4 kernel?  try the 5.3 or 4.15 or whatever is installed)

Answer (score 1):

it is unlikely that a kernel change sabotaged CD burning or the recognition
of burner drives. More likely is that Brasero cannot cope with changes in
the realm of device management by udev or alike.

But first check if your Brasero is using cdrecord as burn backend and if so
whether you get better results if you run Brasero as superuser. If so, then
it is the need of cdrecord for being run with superuser authority.
Consider to switch to the libburn backend of Brasero.

If the backend is already wodim or libburn:

Inspect your drives by xorriso, which gets its informations from libburn
which talks to the drives by traditional kernel ioctls.

Get a list of recognizable devices

```
xorriso -devices
```

For each of the listed /dev files get the list of supported media and media
states

```
xorriso -outdev /dev/sr0 -list_profiles
```

If you see among the output lines

```
Profile      : 0x0009 (CD-R)
Profile      : 0x000A (CD-RW)
```

then the drive states to be able to burn them.
If it can burn DVD, you will see a bunch of "Profile:" lines which name DVD
types.

Put in the medium which you want to use and do

```
xorriso -outdev /dev/sr0 -toc
```

which with an unused CD-R medium should report

```
Media current: CD-R
Media status : is blank
```

It will also tell you the exact drive model and the medium manufacturer

```
Drive type   : vendor 'HL-DT-ST' product 'BDDVDRW GGC-H20L' revision '1.03'
Media product: 97m34s23f/79m59s73f , Mitsubishi Chemical Corporation
```

(One may google for the text snippets "BDDVDRW GGC-H20L" or "79m59s73f" in
order to learn what others experienced.)

If this all looks like expected, then Brasero's recognition of drives and
media states is to blame. There is not much maintainance for Brasero in
these days.
If you don't want to use xorriso as burn program, try whether K3B or Xfburn
work better for you ... or maybe xorriso-tcltk.
If you want to use xorriso, you may ask for help at bug-xorriso@gnu.org.

Have a nice day :)

Thomas

---

Edit 19 Sep 2020:

The drives say that they can burn CD and DVD.
Now show what they say about the medium:

```
xorriso -outdev /dev/sr0 -toc
xorriso -outdev /dev/sr1 -toc
```

Comment: Drive type: vendor 'HL-DT-ST' product 'DVDRAM GH24NSB0
Profile: 0x0015 (DVD-R/DL sequential recording)
Profile: 0x0016 (DVD-R/DL layer jump recording)
Profile: 0x002B (DVD+R/DL)
Profile: 0x001B (DVD+R)
Profile: 0x001A (DVD+RW)
Profile: 0x0014 (DVD-RW sequential recording)
Profile: 0x0013 (DVD-RW restricted overwrite)
Profile: 0x0012 (DVD-RAM)
Profile: 0x0011 (DVD-R sequential recording)
Profile: 0x0010 (DVD-ROM)
Profile: 0x000A (CD-RW)
Profile: 0x0009 (CD-R)
Profile: 0x0008 (CD-ROM)
Profile: 0x0002 (Removable disk)

Comment: Drive type: vendor 'TSSTcorp' product 'CDDVDW SH-224GB' revision 'SB00'
Profile: 0x0015 (DVD-R/DL sequential recording)
Profile: 0x0016 (DVD-R/DL layer jump recording)
Profile: 0x002B (DVD+R/DL)
Profile: 0x001B (DVD+R)
Profile: 0x001A (DVD+RW)
Profile: 0x0014 (DVD-RW sequential recording)
Profile: 0x0013 (DVD-RW restricted overwrite)
Profile: 0x0012 (DVD-RAM)
Profile: 0x0011 (DVD-R sequential recording)
Profile: 0x0010 (DVD-ROM)
Profile: 0x000A (CD-RW)
Profile: 0x0009 (CD-R) (current)
Profile: 0x0008 (CD-ROM)
Profile: 0x0002 (Removable disk)Here are the outputs, should they work?